# Cross platform sound API for games?

Tags: c++, c, api, audio

Is there an API only for sound?

APIs such as [Allegro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_%28software%29) or [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) provide too much for my needs. I simply need a library that can do something like:

```
InitSound();
Sound *door = LoadSound("door.wav");
PlaySound(door,volume);
```

It would also be great if it could support compressed formats such as [Vorbis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) or [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the SFML library. It does provide additional graphics and network features, but what is relevant to this question, is that it also has neat audio package.

Audio features are:

- Uses hardware acceleration whenever possible
- Can load and save standard sound formats: 
  [Ogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg), [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV), [FLAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC), [AIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format), [Au](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format), [RAW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_audio_format), paf, [8SVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8SVX), NIST, VOC, [IRCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRCAM#Software_developed_at_IRCAM), [W64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Limitations), [MAT4](http://www.myformatfactory.com/MAT4-converter), MAT5 [PVF](http://www.arts-humanities.net/specifications/portable_voice_format_pvf), [HTK](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/sacti/corpora/SACTI-1/utterance-audio/README-HTKAUDIO.TXT), [SDS](http://www.fmjsoft.com/fmt/sds.htm), AVR, [SD2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avid_Audio#Sound_Designer_file_formats), [Core Audio Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio_Format), WVE, MPC2K, [RF64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF64)
- Can load all audio resources directly from files in memory
- 3D sound spacialization
- Easy interface for capturing audio
- Manages memory efficiently, so that you don't have to worry about resources lifetime or storage
- Supports streaming for big files; you can even write your custom streaming class for any source (network, ...)
- Supports multi-channels formats (mono, stereo, 4.0, 5.1, 6.1, 7.1)

Website:
http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: Boooo, you beat me by one minute. But yes, SFML is great.

Comment: Read my comment on graham.reeds answer. SFML includes libraries for sound that are lgpl licensed and there are a lot of potential hazards with gpl licensed code. I was going to use SFML for my game but unlike the people at the free software foundation (who seem to already be rich or have other people paying their bills), I would like to keep my hard work proprietary beyond any reasonable doubt. Just some food for thought.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: you must be confused; LGPL != GPL. you can use a library on closed sourced projects. the only constraint is that you provide some licence notice somewhere.

Comment: @v.oddou perhaps you should read the full license text. There are things that are open to interpretation, such as whether or not my application is actually a derivative work or not. Frankly, I'd rather just stay away from anything where the the person extending the license reserves any right to snoop around in what I'm doing to decide if maybe they wanna take me to court to force me to open source my code or not. "Free" Software Foundation. Right.

Comment: SFML is no longer LGPL, but zlib/png: http://www.sfml-dev.org/license.php

Answer (score 12):

Use [PortAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PortAudio). It is a portable cross-platform audio API.

Comment: I've used that too - was very simple to integrate into my project.

Answer (score 10):

If you are use to using OpenGL then you might like to try [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org)?

The API is very similar to OpenGL so you should feel at home.

Comment: OpenAL is noting like OpenGL. It is an API driven more or less by one company, and even this "drive" is recently no longer there. While the API design is nice, the availability on various platforms is not that good. Its Windows implementation is full of quirks and bugs, esp. with HW (including Creative HW).

Comment: It originally started many years ago (iirc) by Sean Palmer (along with OpenML and a couple of others) but only OpenAL gained any momentum.  It found favour on Linux and was used in may ports of Windows games to Linux by Loki games.  The demise of Loki (and argubly Linux as a profitable games platform) killed off OpenAL, not Creative.  My experience of it goes back several years and it seemed okay back then and worked well for simple audio tests.

Comment: I basically shy away from libraries like openAL because of the lgpl license. Anything that contains "gpl" in it, I immediately shy away from and I have no idea why the two gpl licenses are so popular. They're the single most viral licenses I've ever encountered. Sure, you can link to lgpl libraries and it's okay but there is are many obscure clauses in the license that can end up hijacking your application and forcing it to become lgpl too. For example, if your program because "dependent" on types and such within the library, kiss all your work goodbye. Be very wary of anything GPL.

Comment: Dead link. Is this related to https://www.openal.org/?

Comment: Yes. Good catch. Fixed link. CreativeLabs took it over when Loki Games folded who took it over when Sean Palmer created it.

Answer (score 4):

I really like [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/audio-sound.php), it's written in C++ and follows most of the rules of good API design ([RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and so forth).

If you prefer a more "C-like" library, [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) needs to be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

[SDL_sound](http://icculus.org/SDL_sound/) is very simple to use, and handles the decoding for you. If you used [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx), you would have to do the decoding yourself (last I used it, anyway). I actually prefer OpenAL for games, though.

Comment: I have used it and wrapped in in my 2D game engine `carnage engine` but I had surprises from time to time about a valgrind report; or sound cracking the second time it is played over... I wouldn't recommend it today.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but anyone stumbling upon this now might like to check out [FMOD](https://www.fmod.org)

You can make use of the low-level API to start simple then make use of the more powerful features (and FMOD Studio) later-on if required.

Here's the [documentation](https://www.fmod.org/documentation/#content/generated/example_lowlevel/play_sound.html) for playing a sound, which references the samples in the API:

> This example shows how to simply load and play multiple sounds, the
>   simplest usage of FMOD.

I used this low-level API for a cross platform (Mac, Windows) Space Invaders clone I developed and found it very useful!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a professional cross-platform sound design API and authoring application, take a look at [Audiokinetic Wwise](http://www.audiokinetic.com/en/products/wwise/solution-overview). It can do much more than just play sounds. It has effects, complex sound logic system, sound layering, profiling, interactive music tools, etc... It provides [Ogg Vorbis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) and [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) support, and it is free for non-commercial projects.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [Kowalski project](http://kowalski.stuffmatic.com), a cross platform audio API geared towards games and similar interactive applications. It's released under the zlib license.

Comment: "currently being refactored, not quite useable yet," but no commits for the last 8 months.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is only free for non-commercial applications, [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/) is really easy to implement.

*Example of usage:*

```
// initialize device at 44kHz
if (!BASS_Init(-1,44100,0,0,NULL))
{
    printf("Can't initialize device");
    return 0;
}

HSAMPLE sample;
HCHANNEL channel;

// load from disk
if( sample = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE,"foo.wav",0,0,1,BASS_SAMPLE_OVER_POS) ) {

    // get playable channel
    channel = BASS_SampleGetChannel( sample,FALSE);

    // play
    BASS_ChannelPlay(channel,TRUE);

    // wait for playback to finish
    while( BASS_ChannelIsActive( channel ) )
         Sleep(100);

   BASS_SampleFree(sample);
}

// cleanup
BASS_Free();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider [libsoundio](http://libsound.io/). It does not support compression or codecs, but it does provide a robust cross platform sound API. It might be a bit low level for your needs; the library you're looking for might be built on top of libsoundio.

Answer (score 0):

Try **libao** http://www.xiph.org/ao/ - its very simple & supports variety of platforms. I tried it on a raspberry pi with success.

Comment: libao is GPL, not LGPL.