# How to use playSound in c++ to pause and resume the music

Tags: c++, windows, playsound

```
PlaySound(TEXT("bgm.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

was used for playing the background music, however, I find that [Playsound API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx)

does not have any SND_XX for stopping the music? So if I want to stop and resume the music, what should I do?

Comment: I would use a different API all together. I've only ever seen PlaySound used for playing short sounds (i.e. for notifications or alerts in an application), I don't believe its intended for long duration music like in your case.

Comment: This StackOverflow question might provide you with some useful information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636715/cross-platform-sound-api-for-games

Comment: As noted in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx), you can pass NULL to stop an already-playing sound. But there is no resume. You need to use some other sound API for that. PlaySound is for simple sound scenarios.